# how to use stuff function in oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I run a simple query below and outputs the following:

```
select subject_name, charge_section
from Arrest_table a, Charge_table b
where a. charge_id = b.charge_code

Subject_name    Charge_section
Person1     333a.2322
Person2     222a.a6b4
Person2     8usa.1883
Person3     1111.b222
Person3     3233.a332
Person3     8usa.1111
```

How do i write in SQL SERVER or ORACLE platform that can show as follow

```
Subject_name     Charge_section1     Charge_section2     Charge_sector3
Person1     333a.2322
Person2     222a.a6b4             8usa.1883
Person3     1111.b222             3233.a332           8usa.1111
```

Thanks and Happy Holidays everyone!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx). You may use [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get your 1-3 records.